# Looping and String Formation

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have a pretty simple general programming problem, yet I can't quite get the results that I am looking for. Basically, I have a DataGridView called dataGridView3 (2 columns), and I want the user to be able to enter as many fields as he/she desires and create a series of strings based on these fields. My problem is that the formed string can only contain 4 elements of the dataGridView at a time, but with my current implementation, it puts every line in first string (see example).

Here is the code that I am currently using.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 4 == 0)
                {
                    newPA61String += "PA61";
                    for (int j = i; j < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        newPA61String += " " + (dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString().PadLeft(5, leftPaddingChar))
                            + " " + (dataGridView3.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString().PadRight(6, rightPaddingChar));
                    }
                    newPA61String = newPA61String.PadRight(56, rightPaddingChar);
                    newPA61String += "\r\n";
                }        
            }
```

Using 6 rows of data, this code gives me an output of:

```
PA61 00001 a      00002 b      00003 c      00004 d      00005 e      00006 f     
PA61 00005 e      00006 f
```

I would like it to look like this; however, I can't quite manipulate it the way I want:

```
PA61 00001 a      00002 b      00003 c      00004 d 
PA61 00005 e      00006 f
```

My first instinct was just to truncate the first string after the specified length was reached, but the string is formed by placing everything on one line split by a "\r\n", so doing that would eliminate anything after the first 4 columns.

I know the solution is probably fairly obvious, but I'm having one of those days...

Thanks in advance, and if you need any additional information, please ask.

Comment: What does this have to do with recursion?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
for (int j = i; j < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
```

to:

```
for (int j = i; j < Math.Min(dataGridView3.Rows.Count, i + 4); j++)
```

And you can move the Math.Min expression out of the loop.

Though I find while loops clearer for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the number of PA61 items to insert, not over the rows and then calculate row and column (or cell) number like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pa61ItemsCount; i++)
{
    int row = i / 4;
    int cell = i % 4;
    ...
}
```